# Converting PIL GdkPixbuf

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pygobject, gdkpixbuf

How can I convert PIL Image in pixbuf?. I tried to change many examples but no solution

```
import array
from gi.repository import GdkPixbuf

def image2pixbuf(self,im):
    arr = array.array('B', im.tostring())
    height, width = im.size
    return GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_data(arr, GdkPixbuf.Colorspace.RGB,
                                      True, 8, width, height, width * 4)
```

Error

```
TypeError: new_from_data () takes Exactly 9 arguments (7 given)
```

I use Pygobject https://live.gnome.org/PyGObject

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same problem with Gtk3. [GdkPixbuf.PixbufDestroyNotify - NotImplementedError - python gtk3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284465/gdkpixbuf-pixbufdestroynotify-notimplementederror-python-gtk3)

It seems that there is a bug. I have reported it. https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=674691

Gtk3 has this bug. But you can still do it in Gtk2.

Comment: This comment from the bug report might be useful: "so you can
still use `new_from_file()`, or just `new()` and set the data later"

Comment: Yeah I saw that. But I specifically want gdkPixbuf new_from_data()

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it in PyGtk, maybe this still works (I'm copying the code after pygi-convert'ed it):

```
import Image
import StringIO
from gi.repository import GdkPixbuf

def thumbnail_image(self, image):
    """Creates a thumbnail GdkPixbuf of given image"""

    # Create thumbnail
    img = Image.open(image)
    img.thumbnail((200, 300), Image.ANTIALIAS)

    # Convert to GdkPixbuf
    if img.mode != 'RGB':          # Fix IOError: cannot write mode P as PPM
        img = img.convert('RGB')
    buff = StringIO.StringIO()
    img.save(buff, 'ppm')
    contents = buff.getvalue()
    buff.close()
    loader = GdkPixbuf.PixbufLoader('pnm')
    loader.write(contents, len(contents))
    pixbuf = loader.get_pixbuf()
    loader.close()

    return pixbuf
```

Kind regards

---

EDIT: Ok, this seems to be working... I just so hate PyGObject poor C ported API (until now...).

Code (**test.py**):

```
import Image
import StringIO
from gi.repository import Gtk, GdkPixbuf
from os.path import abspath, dirname, join

WHERE_AM_I = abspath(dirname(__file__))

class MyApp(object):

    def __init__(self):
        # Build GUI
        self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
        self.glade_file = join(WHERE_AM_I, 'test.glade')
        self.builder.add_from_file(self.glade_file)

        # Get objects
        go = self.builder.get_object
        self.window = go('window')
        self.image = go('image')

        # Load image
        path = join(WHERE_AM_I, 'logo.png')
        thumbnail = self.thumbnail_image(path)
        self.image.set_from_pixbuf(thumbnail)

        # Connect signals
        self.builder.connect_signals(self)

        # Everything is ready
        self.window.show()

    def main_quit(self, widget):
        Gtk.main_quit()

    def thumbnail_image(self, image):
        """Creates a thumbnail GdkPixbuf of given image"""

        # Create thumbnail
        img = Image.open(image)
        img.thumbnail((200, 300), Image.ANTIALIAS)

        # Convert to GdkPixbuf
        if img.mode != 'RGB':          # Fix IOError: cannot write mode P as PPM
            img = img.convert('RGB')
        buff = StringIO.StringIO()
        img.save(buff, 'ppm')
        contents = buff.getvalue()
        buff.close()
        loader = GdkPixbuf.PixbufLoader.new_with_type('pnm')
        loader.write(contents)
        pixbuf = loader.get_pixbuf()
        loader.close()

        return pixbuf

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gui = MyApp()
    Gtk.main()
```

Glade file (**test.glade**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <!-- interface-requires gtk+ 3.0 -->
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="window_position">center-always</property>
    <property name="default_width">300</property>
    <property name="default_height">200</property>
    <signal name="destroy" handler="main_quit" swapped="no"/>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkImage" id="image">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

What it looks like:

[image: Result of converting PIL Image to GdkPixbuf]

(Improvements to add Alpha channel support are welcome)

Kind regards